# Returning reference to locally dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

Is the behavior of this code well-defined? Will the returned reference always be correct? Will the Bar::method() call always go well?

```
struct Bar
{
    void method() {...};
};

struct Foo
{
    static unique_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr;
    static Bar& get_reference()
    {
        return *bar_ptr;
    }
};

unique_ptr<Bar> Foo::bar_ptr = nullptr;

int main()
{
    Foo::bar_ptr = make_unique<Bar>();
    Foo::get_reference().method();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Constructed instance of `Bar` will be destroyed after `main` returns.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "always". No it would not be correct before you call `make_unique` and sometime after `main()` terminated.

Comment: So am I right that the reference will be correct until the instance of the Bar is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the behavior of this code well-defined?

*Yes* it is.

The instance of `struct Bar` will go out of scope, thus destroyed, after `main()` terminates.